# use of assertions for type checking in php?

Tags: php, oop, assertions

I do some checking of arguments in my classes in php using exception-throwing functions. I have functions that do a basic check ( `===`, `in_array` etc ) and throw an exception on false. So I can do `assertNumeric($argument, "\$argument is not numeric.");` instead of

```
if ( ! is_numeric($argument) ) {
    throw new Exception("\$argument is not numeric.");
}
```

Saves some typing

I was reading in the comments of the [php manual page on assert()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php) that

> As noted on Wikipedia - "assertions
>   are primarily a development tool, they
>   are often disabled when a program is
>   released to the public." and
>   "Assertions should be used to document
>   logically impossible situations and
>   discover programming errors— if the
>   'impossible' occurs, then something
>   fundamental is clearly wrong. This is
>   distinct from error handling: most
>   error conditions are possible,
>   although some may be extremely
>   unlikely to occur in practice. Using
>   assertions as a general-purpose error
>   handling mechanism is usually unwise:
>   assertions do not allow for graceful
>   recovery from errors, and an assertion
>   failure will often halt the program's
>   execution abruptly. Assertions also do
>   not display a user-friendly error
>   message."
>
> This means that the advice given by
>   "gk at proliberty dot com" to force
>   assertions to be enabled, even when
>   they have been disabled manually, goes
>   against best practices of only using
>   them as a development tool

So, am I 'doing it wrong'? What other/better ways of doing this are there?

Comment: Just as a side note: Do you want to validate user input this way? If that is the case, I don't think that invalid user input is something exceptional.

Comment: @Maxem Well, that might happen if I don't code robustly. Basically what I'm doing is rendering the object noticeably useless if the arguments are bad. I like the KISS philosophy.

Comment: What *would* be exceptional is if your user input validator failed and further down in the libraries, they truly expected sane input and got crazy stuff.  *that* would be an exception. The test would be called a sanity check.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd second Wikipedia content and not use assertions for regular type checking.

Instead, I'd use PHP Type-Hinting (currently working on objects as php 5.1 and arrays as of php 5.2 ...won't help you with basic data types, but it's still better than nothing); you can then use the functions you were hinting at or even go a little further and consider Ilia Alshanetsky's patch for general type hinting. [See here](http://ilia.ws/archives/205-Type-hinting-for-PHP-5.3.html).

Comment: I don't know. I mean, type hinting arrays and objects is fine, but if the class really needs an integer, or a non-empty string, doing assertions is frowned upon? I'm not going to be able to install the type hinting patch. Should I continue to do what I'm doing and just not call it assertions?

Comment: Assertions are only meant for debugging and development environments!

Answer (score 0):

As with regular assertions, you should be able to turn your custom assertions *off* via a convenient global constant or variable or class constructor method. They really do not belong (active) in production code, or active by default in any kind of library. For what you are using them to do, it seems like a waste of CPU cycles even if you could turn them off.

In lower level languages, assertions are very useful to catch very strange situations such as bugs created by over-zealous architecture specific compiler optimizations. For instance, you know that in any sane universe, the asserted condition is going to be true. Then your compiler rips apart the fabric of space time and everything changes. So, perhaps they would be useful if you were using something like PHC or Roadsend to compile your app.

I have also seen 'overly secure' code (mostly in C) where the entrance to every single function is guarded by assertions. I *really* question the wisdom of doing that.

In short, you *want* your code to fail gracefully or not at all, not just halt, especially if it depends on user input. Assertions only report conditions that evaluate to false, they don't *handle* errors.

Comment: And why exactly wouldn't you use them in production code? If you have to check for something anyways, you'll use CPU cycles anyways. How significant can the performance hit be if you use assert() for things that should definitely not happen instead of an if check?